# React-Hooks: 'Alert' is undefined in ContextAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create React app for searching movies (I am using Movie Database API) and when i click on a search button if the input is empty i would like an alert component to pop up, however i am getting Alert is undefined error in that same component.

Alert.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import AlertContext from "../context/alert/alertContext";

const Alert = () => {
  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);

  const { alert } = alertContext;

  return (
    alert !== null && (
      <div className={`w-full bg-${alert.type} px-4 py-2 rounded`}>
        <p className="text-white text-center font-mono">{alert.msg}</p>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

GitHub repo:

https://github.com/Ivan3628/find-movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are passing `state.alert` to your context provider when you really just need to pass `state`.  OR you need to define an `alert` property in your reducer.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGMq9.png)

In AlertState.js, instead of this:

```
      value={{
        alert: state.alert,
        setAlert
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AlertContext.Provider>
```

Do this:

```
      value={{
        alert: state,
        setAlert
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AlertContext.Provider>
```

Comment: You're welcome! can you mark it as the correct answer? Trying to build my reputation score here on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing it this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import AlertContext from '../context/alert/AlertContext';

export default function Alert() {

const {alert} = useContext(AlertContext);

if (alert !== null){
    return(
      <div className={`w-full bg-${alert.type} px-4 py-2 rounded`}>
        <p className="text-white text-center font-mono">{alert.msg}</p>
      </div>
    );
}else{
    return;
}

}
```

if that doesn't work, I would recommend using your state to display an alert within your application.

```
//this is a simplified example and may need to be changed based in context.
//in your applicaiton's state:

   this.state = {
     // the rest of your state here
     alertVisibility: false,
     alert: {
        msg: //message goes here,
        type: //type goes here
     }

   }

<div className="alert">
{this.state.alertVisible && <Alert alert={this.state.alert}>}
</div>
```